# How can i upgrade System.Text.RegularExpressions version?

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-devops, devsecops

i am running azure pipline with `Mend Bolt` task to detect old libraries, and i got:

[image]

Notice for `System.Text.RegularExpressions` the existing version is `4.3.1` and the suggested fix is ALSO `4.3.1` but it seems it is not taken in consideration.

PS: my csproj is [here](https://github.com/MohamedBenighil/WebAppWithDatabaseDemo/commit/6cc1bd05fabececa59da249cf3168339b54e979a)

Any help please ?

Thank you in adavance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mend has a [page](https://docs.mend.io/en-US/bundle/wsk/page/is_my_project_vulnerable_to_cve-2019-0820_.html) about this `CVE-2019-0820` issue, explaining when this notice might also be a false positive.

For your situation it is a false positive

- you are on .NET 6, which is higher than the mentioned vulnerable runtimes (see below) - your [WebApp.proj](https://github.com/MohamedBenighil/WebAppWithDatabaseDemo/blob/6cc1bd05fabececa59da249cf3168339b54e979a/WebApp/WebApp.csproj) has `<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>`
- you reference `System.Text.RegularExpressions` version 4.3.1 or even higher.

---

From that page:

> In case the project has the `CVE-2019-0820` reported then if it is actually vulnerable or not **depends on the used .NET Core Runtime version**.

> The vulnerable .NET Core Runtime versions for this CVE are:
>
> - `v1.0` branch: 1.0 - 1.0.16 (exclusive)
> - `v1.1` branch: 1.1 - 1.1.13 (exclusive)
> - `v2.1` branch: 2.1 - 2.1.11 (exclusive)
> - `v2.2` branch: 2.2 - 2.2.5 (exclusive)

> If the user is running a higher .NET core version than listed above while using the package version 4.3.1 then they are secured from the vulnerability and they can safely ignore the alert.